# Insufficient memory with sandisk 32GB micro SD card while having 20GB free space

Tags: external-sd, insufficient-memory, storage

I have a 32GB micro SD card and I've been downloading my music onto it and I've used 8GB on the card so far. Then I was downloading a song and it said insufficient memory. On my phone the songs automatically go to SD card. So I went to storage and it reads the card and says 20GB free space but any app or music or anything cannot be downloaded due to the supposed insufficient space though I know that it's just not true. If anybody else has had this problem please let me know. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading SD formatter. it will format the sd card but it will also fix the partition table. maybe your partition table is all messed up

Comment: OK great. That sounds good to me. I'm going to try SD formatter right now. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me. Greatly appreciated...